# PHP PDO Prepared Statements Caching

Tags: php, mysql, caching, pdo, apcu

I use a class in PHP, that stores some Prepared Statements. I usually use one Statement per Request. Is there a efficient way to cache this class, the connection and the statements? I already looked at APCu, but it doesn’t seem right to me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "cache"? Store the output? If so, what's your cache invalidation model? What's wrong with MySQL's caching mechanism?

Comment: By cache I mean storing the PDO object or the prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to cache it between requests, because prepared statement is bound to a resource and you cannot persist resources between requests.